# Getting date and time with regex

Tags: python, regex, datetime

I'm trying to extract the date and time from a string establish the delta between that and the current date and time.  I tried to convert the regex output from a list to a string and it shows as type=string but is in the following format - ('18:06:39', 'Jan 30 2020').

```
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

string = 'configuration change at 18:06:39 EET Thu Jan 30 2020 by netbrain'
chg_date = re.findall(r"(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) \w+ \w+ (\w{3} \d{2} \d{4})", string)
chg_date_str = ''.join(map(str, chg_date))
now = datetime.now()
now_format = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S, %b %d %y")
time_difference = now_format - chg_date_str
print(chg_date_str)
print(time_difference)
```

I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MattSherman/Desktop/Python/y.py", line 15, in <module>
    time_difference = now_format - chg_date_str
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compute a time delta, you need to do arithmetic with `datetime` instances. You can convert the results of the `findall()` into a `datetime` using the `datetime.strptime()` function as shown:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

string = 'configuration change at 18:06:39 EET Thu Jan 30 2020 by netbrain'
matches = re.findall(r"(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) \w+ \w+ (\w{3} \d{2} \d{4})", string)
chg_date_str = ' '.join(map(str, matches[0]))
chg_date = datetime.strptime(chg_date_str, "%H:%M:%S %b %d %Y")
now = datetime.now()
time_difference = now - chg_date

print(chg_date_str)
print(time_difference)
```

Output:

```
18:06:39 Jan 30 2020
5 days, 16:34:32.661231
```

Comment: Thank you!  Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You have many problems in you code.

- `findall` returns list of tuples. You should iterate in `findall` results or use `search` instead of `findall`
- you join parts of data using `''`, but you need `' '`
- `%y` is wrong pattern for 4-digit year, should use `%Y`
- you converting date to string and trying find difference between two strings...

I think you code should look something like this:

```py
import re
from datetime import datetime

string = 'configuration change at 18:06:39 EET Thu Jan 30 2020 by netbrain'
chg_dates = re.findall(r"(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) \w+ \w+ (\w{3} \d{2} \d{4})", string)
for chg_date in chg_dates:
    chg_date_str = ' '.join(map(str, chg_date))
    chg_date_date = datetime.strptime(chg_date_str, "%H:%M:%S %b %d %Y")
    now = datetime.now()
    time_difference = now - chg_date_date
    print(time_difference)
```

Answer (score 1):

Others answered it but there are 2 main issues.

You were trying to substract 2 strings from each other, python cannot do that, instead you should substract 2 datetime objects. Also, `re.findall()` is returning a list of length 1, so when concatenating `chg_date` into a `chg_date_str` you actually had to concatenate the 0th item in the returned list, which would be `chg_date_str[0]`. It also looks cleaner if you concatenate with a `', '` instead of an empty string, of course, updating the datetime parameters accordingly.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

string = 'configuration change at 18:06:39 EET Thu Jan 30 2020 by netbrain'
chg_date = re.findall(r"(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) \w+ \w+ (\w{3} \d{2} \d{4})", string)


chg_date_str = ', '.join(map(str, chg_date[0]))
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(chg_date_str, '%H:%M:%S, %b %d %Y')

time_difference = datetime.now() - datetime_object
print(chg_date_str)
print(time_difference)
```

outputs:

```
18:06:39, Jan 30 2020
5 days, 19:05:05.272112
```

which I believe is what you want.